# How to Add a quertystring to a link using jquery

Tags: javascript

I have a set of links on my page and some of them start with /mypath, like this `<a href="/mypath/other/stuff">`

I need to add a querystring to the links that start this way, so the result is something like `<a href="/mypath/other/stuff?parent=1234">` with the '1234' being the node id of the node we're currently viewing.

I've sucessfully passed the nid into my js file using drupal settings.  The only part of this I can't get to work is putting the original link in where you see the second `attr('href')`.

My code is as follows:

```
    $('a[href^="/mypath/"]').attr('href', attr('href') + '?parent=' + Drupal.settings.nodeinfo.nid);
```

Instead of that second attr('href') I've tried a number of things and can't figure out what it should be.

Comment: Is the problem with the selector or with the href value? Is it changing the href at all with what you've got here?

Comment: If I put a static url (ie. 'http://google.com') in there instead of the attr('href') it works as expected.   Right now, due to it just erroring, it returns the original url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got nothing to hook onto for that second `attr()` as you're not storing the result of the jQuery call in a variable.

I'd advise using a loop instead:

```
$('a[href^="/mypath/"]').each(function(index, element) {
  var newAttr = $(element).attr('href') + '?parent=' + Drupal.settings.nodeinfo.nid;
  $(element).attr('href', newAttr);
});
```

That will catch any link on the page that matches the path selector.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I figured it had something to do with the href not being defined.  The only thing I don't get about this is what's the 'index, element' part?

Comment: No worries :) Those variables are provided by the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function, I think the docs page can do a better job of explaining than I can